# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Service - Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is it possible to provide a BLE service on Mac OS X?

From the CoreBluetooth docs found here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html it looks like you can just scan for and connect to peripherals. I am looking to act as a perisperhal.

Comment: I've looked at the output of 'class-dump /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/' and also the iOS CBPeripheralManager Demo (https://github.com/KhaosT/CBPeripheralManager-Demo)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible now with OS X Mavericks (10.9). The same CoreBluetooth CBPeripheralManager API for iOS is available on OS X.

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/osx-ble-peripheral).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the IOBluetooth and CoreBluetooth framework header files in Xcode, you'll note that CBCentralManager is there, but unlike iOS, CBPeripheralManager is not there.

So, on OS X, you are able to act as a Central but not as a Peripheral.